# IOS error while using a search bar

Tags: ios, uitableview, uisearchbar

Hi in my app I've a TableView in which I show something and I want to search in this TableView for a text I write in the search bar, so I followed this [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/16873/how-to-add-search-into-a-table-view).
In my app I'm having a problem, when I run the app and I try to search a letter it crash and in xCode I see this information: `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<__NSCFString 0x9e45990> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key name.'`. I checked my Storyboard to see if I have something wrong, but it's all ok. So I guess the problem it's in the code, I will post here my code and I hope you can help me what's wrong.

```
#import "TableWasteViewController.h"
#import "WasteXmlParser.h"
#import "WasteDetailViewController.h"

@interface TableWasteViewController ()

@property(nonatomic,strong)NSArray *arrayWastes;
@property(nonatomic,strong)NSMutableArray *typeOfWaste;
@property(nonatomic,strong)NSMutableArray *typeOfBin;
@property(nonatomic,strong)NSMutableArray *indexWastes;
@property(nonatomic,strong)NSMutableArray *typeOfWasteBackup;

@end

@implementation TableWasteViewController
@synthesize searchBar;
@synthesize filteredWasteArray;
@synthesize typeOfWaste;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    WasteXmlParser *parser = [[WasteXmlParser alloc]init];
    [parser parseWasteXml];
    self.arrayWastes = [[NSArray alloc]init];
    self.arrayWastes = [parser.arrayWastes mutableCopy];
    self.indexWastes = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    typeOfWaste = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    self.typeOfBin = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    for (int i = 0; i < [self.arrayWastes count]; i++) {
        [typeOfWaste addObject:[self.arrayWastes[i] objectForKey:@"type"]];
    }

    self.filteredWasteArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[self.typeOfWaste count]];

    self.typeOfWasteBackup = [self.typeOfWaste mutableCopy];
}

#pragma mark Content Filtering
- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope {
    [self.filteredWasteArray removeAllObjects];

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.name contains[c] %@", searchText];
    filteredWasteArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[typeOfWaste filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]];
}

#pragma mark - UISearchDisplayController Delegate Methods
- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString {
    [self filterContentForSearchText:searchString scope:
     [[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles] objectAtIndex:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchScope:(NSInteger)searchOption {
    [self filterContentForSearchText:self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.text scope:
     [[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles] objectAtIndex:searchOption]];
    return YES;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    //return self.arrayWastes.count;
    if (self.tableWaste == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        return [filteredWasteArray count];
    } else {
        return [self.arrayWastes count];
    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    UIFont *myFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:14.0];
    if (cell == nil) {
         cell  = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.font = myFont;
    cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 2;
    //cell.textLabel.text = [self.arrayWastes[indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"type"];
    if (self.tableWaste == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        cell.textLabel.text = [self.filteredWasteArray[indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"type"];
    } else {
        cell.textLabel.text = [self.arrayWastes[indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"type"];
    }
    return cell;
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableWaste indexPathForSelectedRow];
    WasteDetailViewController *vc = segue.destinationViewController;
    vc.typeOfWaste = [self.arrayWastes[indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"type"];
    vc.typeOfBin = [self.arrayWastes[indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"place"];
    vc.urlPic = [self.arrayWastes[indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"imgUrl"];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

- (IBAction)backToHome:(id)sender {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
@end
```

Thank you!

**UPDATE**
I post here the screen of my storyboard in which you can see the connection of the tableview controller.

[image: Connection for the WasteTableViewController]

Comment: Check out once if you have given the correct classes in your xib. Check out the outlets that you have given. Remove it and and set it again properly and check it.

Comment: I can see the error while I connect the search bar to the Search Display Controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your storyboard once more, there you should find orphan `IBOutlet` called 'name', remove that and build. It should work fine. Good Luck!

Comment: first error was: I named the outlet for the search bar searchBar and xCode calls searchBar too the connection with Search Display Controller. Now I fixed it but still the same I will update my question to show you the connection in my storyboard